# Form submit and redirect doesn't work on iOS

Tags: ios, forms, symfony, redirect, web

Recently, we've noticed an issue having to do with forms, redirects, and iOS on our website. Browsing on an iOS device, using either Safari or Chrome, if you submit any form on our site that uses `action="POST"`, where there is a redirect after POST, there is an error.

In Safari, the error is

> Safari cannot open the page.
>
> The error was: "cannot parse response".

We see the same error in Safari on desktop.

In Chrome, the error is:

> The site can't be reached
>
> The webpage at https://www.altamurrietahomes.com/contact might be temporarily own or it may have moved permanently to a new web address
>
> ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

(The contact form at that url is an example of a form causing this problem)

OSX The forms all work totally fine on all other browsers and platforms tested, except for Safari.

Edit: This project is using Symfony. Here is the controller method for that particular action:

```
/**
 * Contact Page Action
 * 
 * @Route("/contact", name="contact")
 * 
 * @param Request $request
 * 
 * @return Response|RedirectResponse
 */
public function contactAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm('unitycms_sitebundle_contact', new Contact());
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        $this->get('unity_cms_site.mail_helper')->sendMessage('contact', $form->getData());
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('thanks'));
    }
    return $this->render('UnityCMSSiteBundle:Page:contact.html.twig', ['contact' => $form->createView(),]);
}
```

Comment: I just ran into this same problem on a Drupal site. It is very odd. I guess there's no solutions. I will try to check useragent and handle iOS devices differently.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on apache 2.4 and fixed it by removing `Protocols h2 http/1.1` from my virtual host configuration within ssl.conf.